# Have UITableViewCell button action return as unhandled to trigger tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a screen in iOS that is basically a folder listing. It can contain files and folders. When I tap on a folder, I expect to have a new screen show up with the contents of that folder. However, I want to do several things with a file.

I have a `UITableView` with its own custom `UITableViewCell`. On it there are two buttons that I only want to do actions if on a file row. One button performs a segue to another view controller (to see properties). The second button performs an action (download the file). For folders, I also set the `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`. There is also a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method that performs a check to see if it is a folder and show a new screen if it is. (Although I don't know if the check is necessary because it only gets called for folders due to the `accessoryType`.

My issue (I think) is that the order of operations is messing things up on the folder items.

On a folder, if I tap the button that triggers a segue for files, the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method gets called before the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. So my folder does its own segue properly. However, if I tap the action button, the action gets called first, and `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called.

It seems as if the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` setting overrides segues, but not actions.

Is there a result I can return from the action, or some other method I can call, to indicate that the button action is unhandled and the parent action should fire? I know that is often allowed in Windows applications, but I don't know if there is a similar support in Objective-C.

My current workaround is to add a check to the action to see if it is a folder, and then do all the steps I would normally do in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. That works, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution. I am also going to research if I can have two different `UITableViewCell`s in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to respond to you final comment about having multiple types of UITableViewCells in one table, the answer is yes. That would be a much cleaner solution for your issue.

When you are creating the cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` You can use a different cell identifier.

If you are using a UITableView with `Dynamic Prototypes` you can add another cell to your table and give it a different Identifier (Reuse Identifier) under the Attributes Inspector. When you generate the cell, you can simply call the alternative identifier when you are setting your `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Comment: It's a workaround from the actual question, but this is how I should have done things in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add handler for `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` function to catch an event when user tapped accessory button. And ultimately have same code called from this function and from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` if you want them to behave same way.